# Convexity of a log-determinant function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-analysis, determinant

Consider the following log-determinant function

$$f\left( {\bf{X}} \right) = \log |{\bf{A}} + {\bf{B}\bf{X}}^T + {\bf{X}}{{\bf{X}}^T}|$$

where ${\bf{X}} \in {\mathbb R^{K \times K'}}$ and ${\bf{A}}$ and ${\bf{B}}$ are some matrices with proper dimensions. We assume $K' > K$. Therefore, ${\bf{X}}{{\bf{X}}^T}$ is a positive definite matrix and function $f\left( {\bf{X}} \right)$ is well-defined. The goal is to check whether $f \left( {\bf{X}} \right)$ is convex or not. Any hint for this?

Comment: check the case $K=K'=1$

Comment: @LinAlg It could be quasiconvex

Comment: ${\bf XX}^T\in\mathbb R^{K\times K}$. ${\bf BX}$ is not an $\mathbb R^{K\times K}$ matrix. The number of columns is $K'$ for any choice of ${\bf B}$. So ${\bf BX}$ and ${\bf XX}^T$ cannot be added. Furthermore, how can we be sure that the logarithm is well defined without any additional assumptions (the determinant might be negative)?